# Is there any .NET library for converting video streams?

Tags: c#, on-the-fly, video-conversion

I want to convert video formats on the fly. Is there any library in .NET for converting common video formats to each other on the fly (i.e. reading a network stream)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at VLC wrappers. A recent example which mentions streaming is for example:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/nVLC.aspx